# Is it possible to costomize wizard control side bar to look like this?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, asp.net

I want stylize my asp.net wizard side bar to look similar to this :

[image]

http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#vertical

Is it even possible? As far as I know SideBarStyle does not allow much more than changing font color , size etc.

Answer (score 0):

try F12 in IE to see what css styles are being set. you can override with your own by adding the ! in front of the css property you want to override.